# Get text of div

Tags: javascript

I want to get the text of the next id (the text is: "Show More").

```
<div id="show_more_less" onclick="Show_More_Less();">Show more</p>

function Show_More_Less() {
    var str = document.getElementById('show_more_less').text;
}
```

I tried: `.value` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `<div></p>` ???

Comment: see innerTEXT and textContent

Comment: consider using jQuery, as this is right in it's wheelhouse and will save you pain down the road.

Comment: @ginman no... OP does not need a bloated library just to get some text in a node.

Comment: Part of the consideration. Please tell me more about what OP needs from this small snippet of code...

Comment: @ginman OP needs two lines of javascript max.

Comment: @ginman OP here needs 2 lines of code at most. Maybe some other parts of his program would benefit from library X but there's no reason here to answer with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the text of an element in a cross browser way, you can do this :

```
var e = document.getElementById('show_more_less');
var text = e.textContent || e.innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `innerHTML`:

```
var str = document.getElementById('show_more_less').innerHTML;
```

Also you have an opening `<div>` tag and a closing `</p>` tag which is inconsistent. You probably meant:

```
<div id="show_more_less" onclick="Show_More_Less();">Show more</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting?

Comment: I guess someone doesn't like `innerHTML`

Comment: I wonder what would be his cross browser suggested alternative then?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - They meant you need to provide a suggestion which is feasible for all the browser/versions launched so far example IE 1/2/3/4/5/6 :)

Answer (score 1):

Should make some checks to see if `childNodes[0]` exists and if it's a text node, but basically:

`var str = document.getElementById('show_more_less').childNodes[0].nodeValue;`